# Sequelize set limit to max row count

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

From front end I'm sending 2 type of param to *Sequelize*

**1st Param :** `{}`

**2nd Param:** `{page: '1', start: '0', limit: '30' }`

**My Sequelize query:**

```
myTable.findAndCountAll({
    .....
    offset: (req.query.start) ? parseInt(req.query.start) : 0,
    limit: (req.query.limit) ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 30
.........
```

For 1st param by default it's setting **limit to 30**

And for the 2nd param it's setting **limit** as the param sending.

My problem here is, I need to set the default limit for the 1st param to return all row.

Tried to set `null` for default like `limit: (req.query.limit) ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : null` which setting default limit to **10000000000000**, what I don't want.

If there any specific way to do this might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sequelize doesn't provide inbuilt feature for this , One of the solution to the issue is :

```
let limits = {};
if(req.query.limit){
    limits = {
        offset: (req.query.start) ? parseInt(req.query.start) : 0,
        limit: parseInt(req.query.limit)
    }
}

myTable.findAndCountAll({
    .....
    ...limits , // <---- here three dots are ES6 syntax , so don't ignore that)
    .....
});
```

For more detail : **[READ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**

Comment: it's working without three dots. Is it going to mess-up in future if I don't use this three dots.

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon , it will not work when you have limit param available , please check

Comment: Thanks now I see, there is no error and it was giving result without that. That's why I thought it would work, but now I see it's returning all row in grid if it have params available.

Comment: Hi I'm getting error for three dots on my nodejs server. Its working on my local server but giving error for online server.

       `...limits`      
        `^^^`      
     
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

Comment: Check the node js vesrion on your server

Comment: Good answer, but you should also check for limit query (if it exists), if it is not existing in query you will get error "column \"nan\" does not exist".